# Count field, joins, multiple selects

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables. Estimates, Estimate_versions, and customers.

Here is some SQL

```
SELECT estimates.id,
estimates.estimate_number, 
estimates.description,
estimates.meeting_date,
estimates.job_date,
estimates.status,
estimates.price

FROM
(estimates)
LEFT OUTER JOIN estimate_versions estimate_versions ON estimate_versions.estimate_id =     estimates.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers customers ON customers.id = estimates.customer_id
WHERE customers.key = 'JsB4ND90bn'
```

This works -- What I want to do is add a field at the very end of the table. 
Essentially, I want it to 'count', the number of records in estimate_versions, that contain the current rows, estimate.id, here is some non-working pseudocode of what I basically want in the final field

```
count(where estimate_versions.estimate_id = estimates.id)
```

When I try and do a few different ways of achieving this, I usually get ONE row of data, with one number in it. Instead of lets say, 3 records, and the count field containing the appropriate number.

Looking forward to receiving some much needed aid, my SQL skills are weak.

Comment: Your WHERE clause effectively renders your OUTER JOIN on the customers table as an INNER JOIN. So, if that's what you want, then you might as well write it as an INNER JOIN to begin with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT estimates.id,
estimates.estimate_number, 
estimates.description,
estimates.meeting_date,
estimates.job_date,
estimates.status,
estimates.price,
count(estimate_versions.estimate_id)
FROM
(estimates)
LEFT OUTER JOIN estimate_versions estimate_versions ON estimates.id = estimate_versions.estimate_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers customers ON estimates.customer_id = customers.id
WHERE customers.key = 'JsB4ND90bn'
group by
estimates.id,
estimates.estimate_number, 
estimates.description,
estimates.meeting_date,
estimates.job_date,
estimates.status,
estimates.price
```

Comment: You are a life saver, thanks, I had the first part before, but I hadn't included the group by, thank you! Will accept as answer as soon as the 'time' limit is up.

Comment: BTW, I also flipped the order of your LEFT OUTER JOINs.  I assume that your intent was to get all records from ESTIMATES even if they don't have matching records in ESTIMATE_VERSIONS or CUSTOMERS.  But in your original post you made them look like RIGHT OUTER JOINS instead of LEFT.